# Changing default window location from "main monitor" setting

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

For various reasons my triple monitor setup I have to have the "main monitor" on the left side.

I've dragged the task bar to the middle screen and moved my desktop icons to "simulate" the middle screen being the main monitor. The only thing I can't figure out is getting windows to popup by default on the middle monitor, the always popup on the "main" one, which has to be set to the left (VMWare is the main reason for this).

Does anyone know of a way to change the default window location to a monitor other than the "main" one?

Comment: Why can't you have the main monitor in the middle? You quote "various reasons", but more information might be useful.

Comment: @ChrisF - VMWare does not allow multiple monitors with the main monitor to the "right" of any other monitors.

Comment: Ah, fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used the wonderful [Ultramon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/), which has it's own settings for the display which "underride" (?) the Windows settings.

I just set the middle monitor to be the "primary" one via Ultramon and all was OK; I could still use VMWare on three monitors and windows etc. pop up on the right screen!

[image: Ultramon display settings]